# Using Reflection to get number of bytes from PropertyType

Tags: c#

I have a function that determines the field size (in bytes) of a record value. If it is a string, I use Length to return the number bytes. If it is not a string, I call another method that assigns the number of bytes using a switch.

Here is what I have:

```
private int getRecordFieldSize(PropertyInfo recordField,DataRecord dataRecord)
{

     if (recordField.PropertyType.ToString() == "System.String")
     {
          return recordField.GetValue(dataRecord,null).ToString().Length;
     }
     else
     {
           int bytesOfPropertyType = getBytesBasedOnPropertyType(recordField.PropertyType.ToString());
           return bytesOfPropertyType;
     }
}
private int GetBytesBasedOnPropertyType(string propType)
{

    switch(propType)
    {
        case "System.Boolean":
            return 1;
        case "System.Byte":
            return 1;
        case "System.SByte":
            return 1;
        case "System.Char":
            return 1;
        case "System.Decimal":
            return 16;
        case "System.Double":
            return 8;
        case "System.Single":
            return 4;
        case "System.Int32":
            return 4;
        case "System.UInt32 ":
            return 4;
        case "System.Int64":
            return 8;
        case "System.UInt64":
            return 8;
        case "System.Int16":
            return 2;
        case "System.UInt16":
            return 2;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("\nERROR: Unhandled type in GetBytesBasedOnPropertyType." +
                        "\n\t-->String causing error: {0}", propType);
            return -1;
    }

}
```

My question: Is there a way I can avoid using the switch statement to assign the bytes?

I feel like there should be some way to get the number of bytes using Reflection but I can't find anything on MSDN.

I am really new to C# so feel free to rip my code apart.

Thanks

Comment: One quick point: string.Length will not give you the number of bytes used, unless you have set encoding to simple ASCII.

Comment: Good find @CodeCaster. Does look like a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidArno - Thanks for pointing that out David. I just changed my source code to `return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(recordField.GetValue(dataRecord,null).ToString());`.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Thanks for the link to the possible duplicate. I guess I was too hung up on using Reflection and couldn't see the trees through the forest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions for you:

1. Marshal.SizeOf() method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3.aspx)
2. The sizeof keyword (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf%28VS.71%29.aspx)

The latter though will still need a switch statement as it's not possible to do:

```
int x;
sizeof(x);
```

sizeof only works with explicitly stated types, e.g. sizeof(int)

So (1) is your better option in this case (and it will work for all types, not just those in your switch statement).

Comment: Thanks David. I used option 1 and it works perfectly. I appreciate the feedback on the encoding issue as well. I learned a lot and this was a big help!

Comment: It's important to note that those two methods don't necessarily return the same value. `sizeof` returns the managed size, `Marshal.SizeOf` the size used by the p/invoke marshaller.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Thanks for pointing this out. I need to learn more about marshalling to determine if/how this could have an impact on my project.

Answer (score 3):

This may help

```
private int getRecordFieldSize(PropertyInfo recordField,DataRecord dataRecord)
{

 if (recordField.PropertyType.ToString() == "System.String")
 {
      return recordField.GetValue(dataRecord,null).ToString().Length;
 }
 else
 {
       int bytesOfPropertyType = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(recordField.PropertyType);
       return bytesOfPropertyType;
 }
```

}

Comment: That will still give the wrong value for a string.

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. With the change I made to get the UTF-8 byte count (based on David's comment), this solution works perfectly.